# Why app code does not recognize design code?

Tags: kivy

I'm fairly new into programming so this may be lousy question.

I'm watching tutorials of kivy programming (https://youtu.be/k4QCoS-hj-s?list=PLCC34OHNcOtpz7PJQ7Tv7hqFBP_xDDjqg) and I'm stuck at design language code.

Basically, I'm trying to write a design language code (my.kv) for an app (design.py) which should be connected with this lines in design.py, because of "My" in class:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()
```

Also, line in design.py:

```
class MyGridLayout(Widget):
```

is connected to first line in my.kv:

```
<MyGridLayout>
```

However, it seems design.py does not recognize it, even though they are saved in the same folder.

I was thinking problem may be in different operating systems (Linux-Windows) because of types of brackets, but I don't know what is the Windows parallel to Linux angle brackets.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I tried what @NameKhan72 proposed:

from kivy.lang import Builder

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')
        return MyGridLayout()
```

but still getting error - "no such file or directory: "my.kv"".

**EDIT2**

I found the mistake. Of course, it was connected to my experience in programming. I didn't put ":" at the end of "". Now there is no error but after opening app I get a black screen.

I tried everything I found on the web but nothing so far.

This is code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MyGridLayout(Widget):

    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    pizza = ObjectProperty(None)
    color = ObjectProperty(None)

    def press(self):
        name = self.name.text
        pizza = self.pizza.text
        color = self.color.text

       
        print("Hello " + name + ", you like " + pizza + "pizza, and your favorite color is " + color + ".")
      
        self.name.text =""
        self.pizza.text =""
        self.color.text =""
        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This is design code in my.kv:

```
<MyGridLayout>:
    
    name:name
    pizza:pizza
    color:color
    
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name"
                
            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Favorite pizza"

            TextInput:
                id: pizza
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Favorite color"
                
            TextInput:
                id: color
                multiline:False

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.press()
```

Is it typo or what? I rewrited the whole code 2x to be sure but still getting black screen.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! "Does not recognize it" could mean various things, like "the styling is different then I expected", "an error appears", "I only see a black screen" or lots of other things. It helps if you are specific, see also the paragraph "reproducible" on [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If the current answer doesn't solve your problem consider adding a bit more specific description about what you expect and what you actually see.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: "an error appears" - sorry, new to this site :)

Comment: So which error appears? You can edit your question with the necessary information so that we can hopefully help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the kv-file into python:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')
        return MyGridLayout()
```

Comment: This seems to contradict the "by name convention" section in the [kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv), the kv file should already be loaded.

Comment: It does indeed. I see, that OP has followed this convention. If he is correct, then something still went wrong. This is not really a solution, but more a "failsafe" since the file is loaded no matter the name.

Comment: Explicitly loading a `kv` file that follows the name convention (as described by @syntonym) is a bad idea and can lead to errors due to the `kv` file getting loaded twice.

Comment: I'm willing to debate that... I'm basing this on experience, as, for me and my system, no kv file has gotten loaded, whether it followed the convention or not. If it really is an issue with my system, i'd gladly edit the post.

Comment: Tried, still getting errors "no such file or directory: "my.kv"".  @syntonym

Answer (score 0):

The answer my friend is blowing in the wind.

Nope, my problem was saving in wrong file extension. While saving, I writed my.kv but my PC saved it as my.kv.py. That was the reason why code didn't recognize design code.

Thanks for help, surely it'll help me in the future :)

Answer (score -1):

you should use `Builder.load_file("filename.kv")` or `Builder.load_string(""

""")`but to import it use`from kivy.lang import Builder`

Comment: Tried but no luck. Error - "no such file or directory: "my.kv"".